# Stone-Čech compactification. A completely regular topological space is locally compact iff it is open in its Stone-Čech compactification.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, compactness

I would like to show that a completely regular topological space is locally compact iff it is (weak-star) open in its Stone-Čech compactification.

Does this hold in general?

I.e given a compact subset $X$ of a normed space, then is it true that if $\overline{U}= X$ then, U is open iff U is locally compact?

Answer (score 5):

A Tikhonov space is locally compact if and only if it’s open in any of its compactifications.

Let $Y$ be dense in a compact Hausdorff space $X$. Suppose that $Y$ is open in $X$, and let $R=X\setminus Y$. Then $R$ is closed, so for each $y\in Y$ there is an open $V_y$ such that $y\in V_y\subseteq\operatorname{cl}V_y\subseteq X\setminus R=Y$; the closed nbhd $\operatorname{cl}V_y$ of $y$ is compact and Hausdorff, so $Y$ is locally compact.

Conversely, if $Y$ is locally compact, let $y\in Y$, and let $V$ be an open nbhd of $y$ such that $\operatorname{cl}_YV$ is compact. Let $W=\operatorname{int}_Y\operatorname{cl}_YV$; clearly $W$ is an open nbhd of $y$ in $Y$, and $\operatorname{cl}_YW=\operatorname{cl}_YV$. Now $\operatorname{cl}_YW$ is closed in $X$, so it’s equal to $\operatorname{cl}_XW$. Let $U=\operatorname{int}_X\operatorname{cl}_XW=\operatorname{int}_X\operatorname{cl}_YW$. Then

$$U=\operatorname{int}_X\operatorname{cl}_YW\subseteq\operatorname{int}_Y\operatorname{cl}_YW=\operatorname{int}_Y\operatorname{cl}_Y\operatorname{int}_Y\operatorname{cl}_YV=\operatorname{int}_Y\operatorname{cl}_YV=W\,.$$

(For the inclusion see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447865/intro-to-topology-mendelson/447879#447879).)

Next, there is an open subset $G$ of $X$ such that $W=Y\cap G$, so that

$$\operatorname{cl}_XW=\operatorname{cl}_X(Y\cap G)=\operatorname{cl}_XG\,,$$

since $Y\cap G$ is dense in $G$. But then

$$U=\operatorname{int}_X\operatorname{cl}_XW=\operatorname{int}_X\operatorname{cl}_XG\supseteq G\supseteq W\,,$$

so $U=W$, and hence $W$ is open in $X$ as well as in $Y$. Since $y\in W\subseteq Y$, and $y\in Y$ was arbitrary, $Y$ is open in $X$.

Comment: Thanks @Brian. How do we know the closure of $V_y$ is contained in $X\setminus R$ though?

Comment: @rustyracketman: The closure in $Y$ of $V_y$ is compact, therefore it is already a closed set in $X$.

Comment: Sorry. I am a little confused. For instance taking Y itself, then the closure of Y is X, which is certainly not disjoint from R.

Comment: @rustyracketman: You have to pay attention to the space in which the closure is being taken. The closure of $V_y$ **in** ***Y*** is compact, therefore already closed **in** ***X*** as well. The closure of $Y$ in $Y$ is just $Y$, which isn’t compact and therefore is not closed in $X$.

Comment: Yes, I am failing to see why $V_y$ is compact in Y. I mean if we know that, then that direction of the proof is done.

Comment: @rustyracketman: Let’s back up; are you talking about the first half of the proof, or the second half?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I am talking about the first half. Were you too?

Comment: @rustyracketman: There I’m just using the fact that a compact Hausdorff space is regular: $R$ is a closed set in $X$ not containing $y$, so $y$ has an open nbhd whose closure in $X$ is disjoint from $R$ and therefore contained in $Y$. That closure is then compact, since it’s a closed subset of the compact space $X$, and it’s a subset of $Y$, so it’s compact in $Y$.

Comment: Hi Brain, sorry to ask you another question. But I am not seeing the importance of thinking about closure of $V_y$ in $X$ and $Y$ (in the second part). Does it not just follow from the definition of locally compact? If Y is locally compact, it means that every element has a compact neighbourhood, meaning it has an open neighbourhood. Hence Y is open?

Comment: @rustyracketman: But how do you know that $V_y$, the open nbhd in $Y$, is open in $X$? But I did write that part very badly; let me rewrite it, and then see if it makes better sense.

Comment: I have yet another question! Why is it that $Cl_YW$ is closed in X.
Just like you mentioned how open sets in Y may not be open in X. Is the compactness of it in Y helping us? I can't conjure up an argument for it. I very much appreciate your help!

Comment: @rustyracketman: Yes, the fact that it’s compact in $Y$ is crucial. Compactness is intrinsic to the set: it does not depend on the space in which the set is embedded. Thus, a set that is compact in $Y$ is also compact in $X$, and since $X$ is Hausdorff, that means that it’s closed in $X$.

Comment: Would you like to tell me how we get $Y\cap U=W$ by using the fact $Y$ is dense in $X$? I think it might be a result in general topology but I couldn't find it or prove it.

Comment: How do we get $int_X cl_Y W\supset int_Y cl_Y W$?,  I think the interior will become bigger when we consider a subspace topology. Related to this question. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4169105/about-interior-of-a-set-in-a-subspace

Comment: @Yanyu: You are entirely correct, and I must still have been asleep when I wrote those comments. I’ve deleted them and rewritten that part of the answer to make it clearer; let me know if there are still any problems.

Comment: I do wonder how do we get $$=$int_$ $cl_$ $$=$int_$ $cl_$ $$? Since we just know that $cl_X$ $W$ $\subset$ $cl_X$ $G$.

Comment: @Yanyu: (I apologize for not getting to this yesterday.) That was a silly mistake on my part: I accidentally posted some early scratch work instead of the actual argument that I had in mind. I’m a little distracted at the moment — most of my attention currently is on some non-mathematical difficulties elsewhere — but it **should** be okay now.