# Intro to Topology Mendelson

Tags: general-topology

I'm self studying intro to topology by Mendelson and I'm stuck on a book problem. The problem is,

Let $Y$ be a subspace of $X$ and let $A\subset Y$. Denote the $\operatorname{Int}_X(A)$ as the interior of $A$ in the topological space $X$ and $\operatorname{Int}_Y(A)$ as the topological space $Y$. Show that $\operatorname{Int}_X(A)\subset \operatorname{Int}_Y(A)$.

So I see that $A\subset Y\subset X$ and so the $\operatorname{Int}(A)\subset X$. What I don't understand is how can the interior of $A$ vary as you change topological spaces, especially in the case, were one is contained in the other. Also, when we're looking at $A\subset Y$, $A=O\cap Y$ for some open set $O\subset X$, but if we are looking at $A$ in the topological space $X$, does it still have a similar form?

Any hints toward how to approach this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\int}{\operatorname{int}}$Let $X=\Bbb R$ with the usual topology, and let $Y=\Bbb Z$. Let $A=\{0\}$. Then $\int_XA=\int_{\Bbb R}\{0\}=\varnothing$, but $\int_YA=\int_{\Bbb Z}\{0\}=\{0\}$. Here, then, is an example in which $\int_XA\subsetneqq\int_YA$.

If we take $A=Y$, then $\int_YA=\int_YY=Y$, since $Y$ is certainly an open subset of itself. But if $Y$ is not an open subset of $X$, then $\int_XY\ne Y$, and again interiors with respect to $X$ and $Y$ are different. For instance, we might take $X=\Bbb R$ and $A=Y=\Bbb Q$: then $\int_XA=\int_{\Bbb R}\Bbb Q=\varnothing$, but $\int_YA=\int_{\Bbb Q}\Bbb Q=\Bbb Q$.

HINT: To show that in general we have $\int_XA\subseteq\int_YA$, let $x\in\int_XA$. This means that there is a $U\subseteq X$ such that $x\in U\subseteq A$, and $U$ is open in $X$. Let $V=U\cap Y$; $V$ is open in $Y$. Use $V$ to show that $x\in\int_YA$. Since $x$ was an arbitrary element of $\int_XA$, you’ll then be entitled to conclude that $\int_XA\subseteq\int_YA$.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I have a follow up questions. For the example you gave, how is $int_\rrr\{0\}=\emptyset$? Isn't $\{0\}$ a neighborhood of $0$ and so $0\in int_\rrr{0}$, just like how it is in $\zzz$? Am I missing something big? For the hint, can we just say that since $V$ is in the form of what the open sets in $Y$ are, we can conclude it is in $Y$. That is, the open set $U$ that contains $x$ makes a open set in $Y$? Sorry for the long winded response, I'm just trying to wrap my head around this.

Comment: @user85334: $\{0\}$ is not a nbhd of $0$ in $\Bbb R$. A set $N$ is a nbhd of $0$ in $\Bbb R$ if and only if there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\subseteq N$, and if $N=\{0\}$, there is no such $\epsilon$.

Comment: You're right, I should have thought about that more before I posted, I was in the process of editing just now. Thank you for your help, I'll keep working on it.

Comment: @user85334: I think that you may have the right idea about the hint, but I can’t tell for sure. We know that $U\subseteq A$, so $V=U\cap Y\subseteq A\cap Y=A$. Moreover, $V$ is open in $Y$, so ... ?

Comment: I'm thinking about it, it may take a moment.

Comment: Since $x\in V$ and $V$ is open in $A$, we can conclude that $A$ is a neighborhood of $x$ and so  $x\in int_Y(A)$. Was this the conclusion you had in mind?

Comment: @user85334: That’s right. And that proves the result: we’ve shown that if $x\in\int_XA$, then $x\in\int_YA$, and hence that $\int_XA\subseteq\int_YA$.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for your help Brian.

Comment: @user85334: You’re welcome.